# Arrayformula to check if column contains text and pull the number next to it. Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

In desperate need of some assistance with this! 
Wasn't sure how to title this question...

SAMPLE SHEET - [CLICK ME! :)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/3/d/13L4j_dd59zOz3SeRSSyM1Q4n2rtpd-056O7Yse8hfTc/edit?usp=sharing)

In `SupportingSheet!H1` I have the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(G1:G<>"", IF(DASHBOARD!N2<>"", G1:G/DASHBOARD!$P$2-filter(DASHBOARD!O1:O100,REGEXMATCH(DASHBOARD!N1:N100,E1:E100)),G1:G/(DASHBOARD!$M$3)),))
```

The part I struggle with is:

```
G1:G/DASHBOARD!$P$2-filter(DASHBOARD!O1:O100,REGEXMATCH(DASHBOARD!N1:N100,E1:E100))
```

It needs to divide two numbers and then subtract another number. I can't seem to get this formula to pull the correct number. 
It needs to check if the text in `E1:E100` exist in `DASHBOARD!N1:N100`, if yes, pull the number from `DASHBOARD!O1:O100`.

For example, text in `SupportingSheet!E1` can be found in `DASHBOARD!N2`, hence it needs to pull the number from `DASHBOARD!O2`.

Column `SupportingSheet!J` has the actual end result that a formula needs to produce.

It doesn't look like Regexmatch works as an Arrayformula and I am not sure how to go about it.

Please note, that text in `SupportingSheet!E1:E` is not always identical. Often it will have a random number of "space" at the end (long story...). That is why Regexmatch was a perfect option until I realised it didn't work.

Please let me know if further clarification is needed.

Below is an image of the random spaces (non-printable characters) at the end.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G1:G="",,IF(DASHBOARD!N2<>"", 
 IFNA(G1:G/DASHBOARD!$P$2-VLOOKUP(E1:E1000, DASHBOARD!N1:O100, 2, 0), 
 G1:G/DASHBOARD!$M$3))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The formula works great, however, there is another problem that makes this formula slightly unusable. There is often a random amount of non-printable characters (i.e. spaces) at the end of the text in column SupportingSheet!E. Due to this, the lookup doesn't always match text from column SupportingSheet!E and DASHBOARD!N. Is there a way to work around this. I can't change the data at the source to remove those non-printable characters. I added an image to show what I mean. @player0

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G1:G="",,IF(DASHBOARD!N2<>"", 
 IFNA(G1:G/DASHBOARD!$P$2-VLOOKUP(TRIM(E1:E1000), {TRIM(DASHBOARD!N1:N100), DASHBOARD!O1:O100}, 2, 0), 
 G1:G/DASHBOARD!$M$3))))`